# Diagnostics not seen on local but seen on Robot (running ROS MASTER)

Tags: ros, ros-ip, diagnostic-aggregator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having problems with seeing published messages on the /diagnostics and /diagnostics_agg topics on my system. My system has a main robot that is running ROS MASTER and a laptop. I can ssh into the robot and can rostopic echo the topics the msgs. However, on my laptop side, a rostopic list shows the /diagnostics and /diagnostics_agg but with an echo, no messages are seen.

Other topics are viewable on my laptop side as well as on the robot. For example imu/data works for both robot and laptop. Therefore, the ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_IP are set correctly. Only /diagnostics and /diagnostics_agg do not work.

Has anyone come across this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209175/diagnostics-not-seen-on-local-but-seen-on-robot-(running-ros-master)./) by [keshavi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22421/keshavi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't seen anything like this before.

I would start by trying to identify the nodes that are publishing to the /diagnostics topic, and then I would look at the other topics they're publishing to see if any of those topics can be subscribed to from a remote machine.

I would also compare the node URI (reported as part of `rosnode info`) between a node that publishes topics that don't work, and a node that is working.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [keshavi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22421/keshavi/) on 2015-05-14**:
The imu actually also publishes to the /diagnostics topic using the diagnostic updater package as well as the imu/data topic. It looks like the only thing that isn't subscribed is the /diagnostics.

Checking rosnode info, it seems the node URI's are correct.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-05-14**:
I've never seen a situation where I could subscribe to one topic from a node, but not another topic published by the same node. Are you certain that your diagnosis is correct, and that you can subscribe to IMU data from your laptop, but not diagnostics?

**Comment by [keshavi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22421/keshavi/) on 2015-05-14**:
I have found out that my laptop and the robot are not running the same ros distro. It seems that the diagnostics package has been updated since hydro.